# より not used for comparing?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-より

The title of a piano arrangement of a Touhou song (Hakurei Reimu's Theme) is:

> 「東方永夜抄 - Imperishable Night.」 より 博麗霊夢のテーム

**(Question)** What does `より` do in the title?

If it were to mean "from the game "Imperishable Night"", would `から` be just as suitable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`より` as well as `から` means 'from'. This is the primary meaning. Many languages use the word corresponding to 'from' for introducing the standard for a comparative. It is the comparative usage that is the derived meaning.

Answer (score 7):

There are many uses of より that are not comparative per se.

In some communications, when A writes to B, A starts his letter with "Bさんへ" (To B).  And when he signs, A writes "Aより" (From A).

Also , one can write "ニンテンドー3DS 本日より値下げ、新価格 1万5000円" to express "Starting today, the 3DS becomes cheaper with a new price of 15000 JPY".

Moreover, as a source of information is cited, より is often used: 天気予報により明日は雨です: according to the weather forecast, it will rain tomorrow.
(Nota bene: in this case, より is the verb よる in 連用形, hence the presence of particle に before it.  One could also say "によって" or "によると".)

Finally, your case is also a source (but not a retransmission of information nor a citation).  It's just "from".  This feels (and probably is) more formal than "から", and is very common.

Comment: I think `より` in `天気予報により` is different.

Comment: hum, because it's よる in 連用形?  I agree, but would it be possible that the particle comes from it?  After all, it shows the source/origin too…

Comment: Yeah. It may be related historically. But they belong to different categories. It is a verb, and the other one is a particle.

Comment: As a separate matter, I do not think that 天気予報により明日は雨です is correct.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct that より means from, and can be replaced with から. - rdbより